# List View not displaying divider for 1st item with Text View on top

Tags: android, android-listview, header, textview

I have a Text View on top of list view but the list is not displaying the header divider line, but if i remove the textview and keep only the list view then the header divider line is displaying.

i have tried this too : `HeaderDividerEnabled : true` but not working.

```
 <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"/>
        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:divider="@color/black"
            android:dividerHeight="0.8dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/selector">
        </ListView>
```

Comment: try adding `android:dividerHeight="1px"`... i.e. px instead of dp

Comment: any specific reason to use Relative layout..

Comment: @KingCobraa yes i have some more views to be displayed which are tobe placed in left right of some other view

Comment: can you please post your design..

Comment: @CRUSADER nope its not working i tried that

Comment: just make prototype in paint and post .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33064/discussion-between-king-cobraa-and-goofy)

Comment: @KingCobraa No i cant as its not yet decided which all view to be added but we have this idea for future reference, but how does this have effect onlist view

Answer (score 0):

That is not what android:headerDividersEnabled is supposed to do. It means that if you are adding a list header whether that header needs to be separated by a divider or not.

Here is a working example:  stackoverflow.com/a/8819402/915756

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hi Goofy"
        android:textSize="30sp" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:divider="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:dividerHeight="0.8dp"
        android:entries="@array/hh"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
        android:overScrollMode="never" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

/// border

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
   <!-- use this for transparent -->
   <!-- <solid android:color="#00000000" /> -->
   <!-- use this for a background colour -->
   <solid android:color="#FFF" />
   <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#FF0000" />
</shape>
```

Comment: In list view just delete the entries and put your data.

Comment: ok i will try this, but just can we do it without adding views?

Comment: Just set the border for listview see my update...i set red color ,you can use same color what you have in your divider